# Report Builder can StripLines render on top of chart data?

Tags: reporting-services, label, reportbuilder3.0, datapoint

can horizontal striplines on a column chart render on top of the data?  My chart is rendering like this;

[image]

but I want the stripLine to be visible over the top of the data columns not below it.  I am able to put the dataPoint text that you can see on top, even though i'd rather it be able to render to the right of the bar, but that doesn't seem to be possible either.  any help would be great. Seems like some of these things would be pretty straight forward functionality for such a dynamic report builder but im also a layman.

Answer (score 0):

Striplines are always in the background.

I would add a new Series to the Chart, and change the Chart Type to Line.  For the value I would point at a Goal column in the datasource.  If none is available you can use an expression or hard-code the value.

The sequence of the series controls which is infront of the other.  You can drag the series around to reorder them.

Comment: Put when I do that since I only have 1 Series that's a chart type of "line" it just creates the 1 point on the graph with the label, it doesn't actually draw a horizontal line across the entire graph.  Would just 1 series be able to draw a line across to entire chart? sorry im new with report builder

Comment: Did you use a Goal column in the datasource?

Comment: yea, i have a column called "BasicNeed" that contains an integer value, in the case above "41000."  I think my problem is I don't have any category or series groups as I only want the two bars and the goal line (orange above) to appear once, i'm not sure what i would actually categorize anything on

Comment: Tricky. I would try to "Pivot" the dataset so that the two columns feeding the column series appear in one column on two rows, with a category column containing their label.  Then you should get two rows with the same BasicNeed value, and your line series should spread across the two bars.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to increase the transparency of the color of the columns. click on chart, click on custom palette color in Properties on the right hand-side and specify level of transparency in the color's options.

P.S. I had the same issue and that's how I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Contrary to what I am reading here, it is possible to have the stripe lines on the front as well. However, you will need to create another Series specify the top and bottom value dynamically, and adjust the PointWidth to lets say 0.8 or something along those lines.

Alternatively, you can add in a bar graph with a line graph, that should do it as well.